# Routers in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, debugging, react-router, next.js

I am making changes to my existing application which is built using ReactJS+Typescript and I have been migrating it to NextJs along with Typescript.

How can I make changes to the Router? I check the documentation of Nextjs but I am getting very confused.

Currently the routing is in my **App.tsx** file. Here is the code. I want to make changes because when I click on handleSave at that time, my blog post is not getting saved. I believe the issue lies due to the routing.

```
    return (
      <div className="All-Routes">
        <Switch>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            component={props => <Index {...props} posts={this.state.posts} />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/posts/:id"
            component={props => (
              <Data {...props} post={this.state.posts[props.match.params.id]} />
            )}
          />
          <Route
            exactpath="/new"
            component={props => <Saving {...props} onSave={this.handleSave} />}
          />
        </Switch>
        <LocationDisplay />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Nextjs routes has different way of handling routes.
Each file inside `pages` folder is a route.

Therefore, There is no need for the `Switch` component (which probably comes from `react-router`), in Next there is not Component that "holds" the routes in it self.
There is a reason for that, Next provides SSR, if the routes are part of Component, it needs to render it in order to decide which Component to render.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a routes.js file like below:

```js
const nextRoutes = require('next-routes')
const routes = (module.exports = nextRoutes())

routes.add('/', 'index')
```

and write a server.js with expressjs and add the following line to it:

```js
const routes = require('./routes')
const handler = routes.getRequestHandler(app)
...
server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    handler(req, res, parsedUrl)
  })
```